# Translation of La Prise de la Bastille (song)

Tags: anglais, histoire

What is the translation of the old revolutionary song “La Prise de la Bastille”, particularly the following phrase:

> R’li r’lan r’lan tan plan
>   Tire lire en plan

The lyrics can be found [here](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_prise_de_la_Bastille) and a recording from YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/yqSrFX_E9GA).

The *”r’li”* construction looks like nothing else I have seen in French and I would like to know where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possible translation of "R’li r’lan r’lan tan plan
Tire lire en plan"; it's just as what you find in "[Little drummer Boy](https://www.lacoccinelle.net/954059.html#content-menu-0)", as reproduced below. However, as is suggested in the comments (jlliagre) a rendering might eventually be decided upon.

> Pa ra pam pam pam
>   Ra pum pum pum,
>   Ra pum pum pum

A longer extract from that song shows that this is not translated.

**Come they told me**
Venez ils m'ont dit
**Pa ra pum pum pum**
**A new born king to see**
Qu'un nouveau-né roi est à voir
**Pa ra pum pum pum**
**Our finest gifts we bring**
Nos plus beaux cadeaux nous apportons
**Pa ra pum pum pum**
**To lay before the king**
Pour poser devant le roi
**Pa ra pam pam pam**
**Ra pum pum pum,**
**Ra pum pum pum**

Very probably "R’li r’lan r’lan tan plan" has been made up to reproduce the sound of drums; as we find an R-sound in  sound of the drums for "Little Drummer Boy" we also find one in the mimicked sound of the drums in this revolutionary song.

"Tire lire" in "Tire lire en plan" has nothing to do with "tirelire", that is "piggybank"; again, those words are merely words used for rhyming sounds.

I'm aware of no translation of the song, but I could make one up; here it is below.

Firmly forging ahead in triumph
The burgher at the sound of drums
Is marching to the Bastille
And everywhere is felt his ardour

(The burgher and the merchant
Are marching to the Bastille)

Citizens of all walks of life
Behind the flying colours
Are marching forth undaunted
Nothing cows them down

On all sides can be heard
The sounds of thundering brass
Aimed at the citadel
O! fatal Bastille!

Thou will before long
Thou will before long
Yield to the triumphant arms
Of your besiegers

Get out of your funereal dungeons
Victims of a detested rule
See through the darkness
Liberty's rays
For too long gloomy sadness
Filled your hearts with poison
Bathe in tears of joy
Your liberators brow

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I would spell burger *burgher* to make it clear that it’s the feudal class not the food but that’s not too important

Comment: Many established onomatopeia do have "official" translations (e.g. *cocorico* - *cock-a-doddle-doo*) and you can always coin some for those that have none. ***R’li r’lan r’lan tan plan, Tire lire en plan*** might be translated with ***Tum-ti-tum-ti-tum, Rum-ti-tum ti-tum***...

Comment: @jlliagre Is "Tum-ti-tum-ti-tum, Rum-ti-tum ti-tum" a rendering of your own making?

Comment: It is not. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rum-ti-tum https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/redirect/post?p=13479811